# Highlight duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare 2 columns in excel and highlight duplicates in both. But there are two problems here:

1- I want this comparison to be case sensitive

2- I want to highlight the first occurrence only

It will be great if the script has 2 scenarios:

First: It highlights duplicates at both columns and between them too so the result should be like

[image: Case 01]

In this case:

1) Highlight duplicates within column A, column B, and compare A and B columns to find duplicates too

2) Whenever it find duplicates it highlight ONLY first occurrence of it

Description:

A1 = kar32 > It is duplicate with A3 and it's the first occurrence

A5 = mic > It is duplicate with A6 and it's the first occurrence

A8 = fab > It is duplicate with B3

A9 = tea > It is duplicate with A11 and it's the first occurrence

B1 = kar32 > It is duplicate with A1

B2 = mic > It is duplicate with A5

B3 = fab > It is duplicate with A8

B4 = Fat > It is duplicate with B6 and it's the first occurrence

Second: It highlights first occurrence duplicates between both columns and ignores the only duplicates in the same column

[image: Case 02]

In this case:

1) Highlight ONLY duplicates between columns A and B and ignores duplicates found in the same column

2) Whenever it find duplicates it highlight ONLY first occurrence of it

Description:

A1 = kar32 > It is duplicate with B1 and it's the first occurrence

A5 = mic > It is duplicate with B2 and it's the first occurrence

A8 = fab > It is duplicate with B3 and it's the first occurrence

As you see, it ignores to highlight A9 = tea, B4 = Fat because they didn't have duplicates in other column

Comment: how fab is getting high lighted , are you comparing column A vs Column B ?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting.

One caveat, row 1 needs to be blank or titles that are not in the list being tested.

Select A2 and manage rules.  Add a formula rule.  Then add the following formula:

```
=AND(OR(SUMPRODUCT(EXACT($A:$A, A2)*1) > 1,SUMPRODUCT(EXACT($B:$B,A2)*1)>0),SUMPRODUCT(EXACT(A$1:A1,A2) *1)= 0)
```

Then change the "applies to" to the entire range of cells in column A.

Repeat for column B, but use the following formula:

```
=AND(OR(SUMPRODUCT(EXACT($A:$A, B2)*1) > 0,SUMPRODUCT(EXACT($B:$B,B2)*1)>1),SUMPRODUCT(EXACT(B$1:B1,B2) *1)= 0)
```